# Best Practice: Upload image, perform server side checks, get response

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm wondering how to best go about the following scenario in Firebase:

- Send an image along with some data, specifically an upload code that users have received before (EDIT: there are 100s to 1000s of valid codes)
- Perform server side checks on the data. The image (and associated data) should only be stored if the upload code is valid
- Return a response to the user (Success or Failure i.e. invalid code)

One approach is to use a custom cloud function that does exactly that, but other posts suggest it's faster/more efficient to directly upload to cloud storage and perform the checks in a triggered function. But then, how do I get a success/failure response to the client?

EDIT: Target platform is Web/JS.

Comment: You may be overcomplicating it - Firebase Rules can do all of that; only allow an image to be updated if the user presents a valid, pre-determined 'code' and if it fails return a response to the user. However, this question is very broad and we don't know what platform you're using.

Comment: Thanks @Jay, didn't think of using rules. Looking at Storage Rules specifically, it seems like the list of valid codes has to be 'hardcoded' into the rule. Could this become an issue once the list of codes grows to potentially 1000s and more?
Btw the target platform is Web/JS.

Comment: Well, the question states *there are 100s to 1000s of valid codes* which means you already have a list of them. You would not create or store them in the rules, you would store the codes (and links to the Storage image url) in the Firebase Database (for example) and the rule would validate the code a users enters matches one of the codes in the Database. That would enable you to remove or add codes on the fly as needed, tie them to a particular user or a group of users.

Comment: Having the codes in a Cloud Firestore database would be ideal, indeed. But the rule governing the image upload has to be implemented in Cloud Storage, right? And looking at the [documentation for Storage Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/storage/) I don't see how to access a Firestore Database, or am I missing something?

Comment: You can leverage Cloud Firestore for the entire project and since that's the way Firebase is headed, then it would be the right choice. I was using the Database/Storage as an example but you could do the same thing with Firestore.

Comment: I don't quite understand, could you elaborate a bit please? You mean storing the images in Cloud Firestore as well?

Comment: Well not really. Technically you could store a small thumbnail in Cloud Firestore but Storage is a better solution. You would leverage Firestore in the same way you would Firebase Database; store the Storage URL and lean on the rules to govern access to that URL (for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of the Cloud Function triggered by Storage, you would write, with the Cloud Function, the response status (success or failure) to a specific node of the Real Time database (or a specific Firestore document) and add a listener in your front end on this node (or document)

Comment: Thanks Renaud, that seems workable. As I understand it, the sequence would be something like: 
- Client creates a new document using a UUID. Client adds onSnapshot listener to the doc.  
- Client uploads the image to Cloud Storage, along with extra data including doc id as custom metadata.  
- Cloud Function is triggered by the upload, performs checks etc. and updates the response doc.  
- Client side listener is triggered by the update, notifies user.  
- Client deletes the doc.

---Would you run some periodic cleanup routine to throw out old response docs that might be left?

Comment: That seems perfect! Note that when you say "Client creates a new document using a UUID", you can let Firebase database/Firestore generate the unique id.